# Can i get glowing obsidian on minecraft bedrock on android

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, android

I went to the nether and the end looking for it but i can't find it.

Comment: Do you mean glowstone? Glowing obsidian doesn't exist without mods. And yes glowstone is in the nether...look around the ceilings. Also, instead of posting to Arqade just google that question because it would've gotten you an answer much quicker.

Answer (score 0):

Glowing obsidian was removed, so it`s no longer obtainable, but it has been replaced with glowstone, which can be found in the nether, on ceiling.